# Como leer aun respuesta de tipo json devuelta en una consulta ajax en javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, datos

Estoy realizando una consulta a tabla de BD haciendo uso de la ajax, pero en las respuestas que estas es de tipo json, como puedo obtener

Esta es la estructara de mi codigo:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"ajax/factura.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(respuesta){
        var codigo = respuesta["id"];  //lectura correcta
        var importe = respuesta["total"];  //lectura correcta
        var fecha = respuesta["fecha"]; //lectura correcta
        var listaProductos= respuesta["productos"]; //lectura dato tipo json
        $("#nuevaListaProductos").val(listaProductos);  //No me muestra nada
    }
 })
```

respuesta["productos"] es mi datos Json que necesito leer para realizar otra consulta

Comment: $("#nuevaListaProductos").val(productos);
pero aqui estas mostrando una variable productos pero arriba dice listaProductos osea de donde sale esa variable productos?

Comment: Haz un `console.log(listaProductos);` y dinos qué muestra. Si tuvieras ahí una lista, como parece ser, entonces tendrías que recorrer el JSON con un bucle para ir mostrando los datos que te interesan usando sus nombres de propiedad, tal y como haces más arriba.

Comment: Ahora coloca lo que te muestra consola **respuesta** para saber que trae en total y ayudarte

Comment: cosole.log(respuesta) muestra lo siguiente
console.log(respuesa) esta devolviendo lo siguiente:
0: "34", 1: "10034", 2: "1", 3: "2", 4: "5",5: "Contado",
6: "[{\"id\":\"10\",\"nombre\":\"pvrt\",\"descripcion\":\"pvrt\",\"cantidad\":\"1\",\"stock\":\"20\",\"antes\":\"21\",\"precio\":\"126\",\"total\":\"126\"}]"
7: "0",8: "2970",9: "0",10: "3445.2",11: "3500",12: "54.8",13: "Efectivo",14: "2021-10-27 10:08:20",cambio: "54.8",codigo: "10034",descuento: "0",efectivo: "3500",fecha: "2021-10-27 10:08:20"

Comment: Esta es la otra parte del resultado
cambio: "54.8"
codigo: "10034"
descuento: "0"
efectivo: "3500"
fecha: "2021-10-27 10:08:20"
id: "34"
id_cliente: "1"
id_sucursal: "5"
id_vendedor: "2"
impuesto: "0"
metodo_pago: "Efectivo"
neto: "2970"
productos: "[{\"id\":\"10\",\"nombre\":\"pvrt\",\"descripcion\":\"pvrt\",\"cantidad\":\"1\",\"stock\":\"20\",\"antes\":\"21\",\"precio\":\"126\",\"total\":\"126\"}]"
tipo_venta: "Contado"
total: "3445.2"

Comment: console.log(listaProductos) muestra todo el contenido de respuesta["productos"]
[{"id":"10","nombre":"pvrt","descripcion":"pvrt","cantidad":"1","stock":"20","antes":"21","precio":"126","total":"126"}]

Comment: Ponlo en la Pregunta, para asi leer correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Es justo como sospechaba. En `listaProductos` tú tendrías un array de objetos JSON. Para leerlo deberás hacer uso de un bucle (a no ser que sólo quieras un elemento en específico).

Veamos un ejemplo donde leerías los elementos por su clave : valor de forma dinámica (dado que estás usando jQuery, usaremos la función `$.each` de dicha librería):

```js
//var listaProductos= respuesta["productos"]; //lectura dato tipo json

/* Creamos la variable aquí para prueba*/
var listaProductos = [{
  "id": "10",
  "nombre": "pvrt",
  "descripcion": "pvrt",
  "cantidad": "1",
  "stock": "20",
  "antes": "21",
  "precio": "126",
  "total": "126"
}]

var htmlProducts = "";

$.each(listaProductos, function(k, item) {
  $.each(item, function(key, value) {
    htmlProducts += (`${key} \t: ${value}<br />`);
  });
  htmlProducts += ('<hr />');

});
//console.log(htmlProducts);  

$("#nuevaListaProductos").html(htmlProducts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nuevaListaProductos"></div>
```

Si por algún motivo quisieras obtener las propiedades por su nombre, también puedes hacerlo. En ese caso con un solo bucle bastaría:

```js
//var listaProductos= respuesta["productos"]; //lectura dato tipo json

/* Creamos la variable aquí para prueba*/
var listaProductos = [{
  "id": "10",
  "nombre": "pvrt",
  "descripcion": "pvrt",
  "cantidad": "1",
  "stock": "20",
  "antes": "21",
  "precio": "126",
  "total": "126"
}]

var htmlProducts = "";

$.each(listaProductos, function(k, item) {
  htmlProducts += (`id: \t: ${item.id}<br />`);
  htmlProducts += (`nombre: \t: ${item.nombre}<br />`);
  htmlProducts += 'etc ...<br />';

});
htmlProducts += ('<hr />');

$("#nuevaListaProductos").html(htmlProducts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nuevaListaProductos"></div>
```